¿Cómo añadir varios estilos CSS con JavaScript al ser visible en el viewport?
Estoy utilizando este código para cargar un estilo CSS que reproduce una animación, mi pregunta es.. ¿Cómo puedo añadir más de un estilo?
He probado con:
entry.target.classList.add('animate', 'animate2'); 

Pero no me funciona. Solo funciona con 1.
Gracias
// Crear el observador (Intersection Observer API)
// En la función anónima se recibe una lista de entradas,
//    no importa que solo se observe un elemento
observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  // Recorrer las entradas recibidas
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Está visible en el viewport
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      // entry.target es el elemento que se está observando
      // Agregar la clase para animar
      entry.target.classList.add('animate');
      // Dejar de observar
      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
  });
});
// Observar elemento a animar
observer.observe(document.querySelector('#cube'));


Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Tratando de usar términos correctos, no añades estilos como tal, sino que añades clases a los elementos.  Un elemento puede tener varias clases asociadas y según la documentación de add() si puedes agregar varias clases a la vez, separadas por comas. ¿En qué te basas para decir que no funciona?

Por otro lado, para este tipo de preguntas, suele resultar mejor si preparas un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Cuando varios estilos CSS tienen animación y un elemento tiene varios de esos estilos asociados, estas animaciones no se ejecutan en paralelo, al menos en Chrome y Firefox. Ignoro si este comportamiento es estándar o está documentado y no encontré ninguna referencia rápida.
OJO, puedes tener un único estilo que ejecute varias animaciones a la vez, pero no varios estilos ejecutando una animación cada uno.
Para hacerme entender mejor, he preparado el siguiente ejemplo.
Creo que el código se explica por sí solo. La idea básica es tener un elemento al que podemos resetear la animación para ir asociando varias clases que tienen animaciones.
Puedes ver que, si aplicamos una clase, la animación ocurre sobre el elemento.
Cuando aplicamos ambas clases a la vez, solo se puede observar la segunda animación, pues aunque tiene la primera clase asociada, esta animación no tiene efecto. De hecho, dado que siempre se va a asignar primero una clase y un instante después la otra, en realidad la primera animación comienza por ese breve instante, pero luego es cambiada y solo la segunda es visible.
Si aplicamos los estilos con una espera, puedes ver como esto ocurre de una manera más clara.
Finalmente, si aplicamos una única clase que combina ambas animaciones, puedes observar como estas ocurren al mismo tiempo.


const div = document.querySelector('div');
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
function reset_animation() {
  div.classList.remove('animacion1');
  div.classList.remove('animacion2');
  div.classList.remove('animacionCombinada');
  div.style.animation = 'none';
  div.offsetHeight; /* trigger reflow */
  div.style.animation = null; 
}
function comenzar1() {
  reset_animation();
  div.classList.add('animacion1');
  console.log(div.classList.value);
}
function comenzar2() {
  reset_animation();
  div.classList.add('animacion2');
  console.log(div.classList.value);
}
function comenzarAmbas() {
  reset_animation();
  div.classList.add('animacion1', 'animacion2');
  console.log(div.classList.value);
}
async function comenzarEspera() {
  reset_animation();
  div.classList.add('animacion1');
  console.log(div.classList.value);
  await sleep(3000);
  div.classList.add('animacion2');
  console.log(div.classList.value);
}
function comenzarCombinada() {
  reset_animation();
  div.classList.add('animacionCombinada');
  console.log(div.classList.value);
}
.base {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
.animacion1 {
  animation-name: posiciones;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
.animacion2 {
  animation-name: colores;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
.animacionCombinada {
  animation: posiciones 4s, colores 4s;
}
@keyframes posiciones {
  0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {left:200px; top:0px;}
  50%  {left:200px; top:200px;}
  75%  {left:0px; top:200px;}
  100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}
@keyframes colores {
  0%   {background-color:red;}
  25%  {background-color:yellow;}
  50%  {background-color:blue;}
  75%  {background-color:green;}
  100% {background-color:red;}
}
<h1>Animaciones CSS</h1>
<div class="base"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="comenzar1()">Animación 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="comenzar2()">Animación 2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="comenzarAmbas()">Ambas al tiempo</button>
<button type="button" onclick="comenzarEspera()">Ambas con espera</button>
<button type="button" onclick="comenzarCombinada()">Combinación</button>



Si tienes dudas, déjame un comentario.

Creo que me has ayudado mucho, muchas gracias.
